# Xamarin Forms TapGesture Animation Issue

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to show the second stack layout when the first stack layout is clicked with an animation. It works well after the first attempt.

My question is the animation doesn't work for the first attempt.

code -

```
private TapGestureRecognizer tg;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        answerStack.IsVisible = false;

        tg = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tg.Tapped += Tg_Tapped;
        questionStack.GestureRecognizers.Add(tg);
    }

    public Animation animate;

    void Tg_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var answerHeight = answerStack.Height;

        answerStack.IsVisible = !answerStack.IsVisible;
        questionStack.GestureRecognizers.Remove(tg);

        animate = new Animation(d => answerStack.HeightRequest = d, 0, answerHeight);

        animate.Commit(answerStack, "a", 5, 450, Easing.CubicIn, (data, x) => {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                answerStack.HeightRequest = answerHeight;
                questionStack.GestureRecognizers.Add(tg);
            });
        }, null);
    }
```

GitHub Link - https://github.com/manieshavirt/XamarinAccordion

The reason for the issue is,"answerHeight" is set to -1 during the first animation. In subsequent animations,"answerHeight" is derived from the height of the answer-content, hence there is a smooth animation.If I manually set a value for "answerHeight" during the first animation, the animation transition appears smoothly. However, I do not want to set a value manually, instead, I need to derive the value from height of the answer-content during the first animation.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have the same issue: First animation is not shown. My (dirty and bad) workaround is to call an animation once which shows the initial state